# CubeMX-generated USB HID device sends wrong data when both endpoint and PMA address are changed

Tags: usb, stm32, cubemx, stm32f3

I'm debugging a problem with a composite device that I'm creating, and have recreated the issue in freshly-CubeMX-generated HID-only code, to make it easier to resolve.

I've added small amount of code to `main()` to let me send USB HID mouse-clicks, and flash an LED, when the blue-button is pressed.

```
...
uint8_t click_report[CLICK_REPORT_SIZE] = {0};
extern USBD_HandleTypeDef hUsbDeviceFS;
...
int main(void)
{
  ...
  while (1)
  {
      /* USER CODE END WHILE */

      /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(B1_GPIO_Port, B1_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_SET){
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD4_GPIO_Port, LD4_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

          click_report[0] = 1; // send button press
          USBD_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, click_report, CLICK_REPORT_SIZE);
          HAL_Delay(50);

          click_report[0] = 0; // send button release
          USBD_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, click_report, CLICK_REPORT_SIZE);

          HAL_Delay(200);

          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD4_GPIO_Port, LD4_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      }
  }
```

I am using Wireshark and usbmon (on Ubuntu 16.04) to look at the packets which my STM32F3DISCOVERY board sends.

With this freshly-generated code, I can see `URB_INTERRUPT` packets being sent from 3.23.1.  (Only the last part of that address, the endpoint, is relevant.)

The packet contents are:

```
01 00 00 00
00
00 00 00 00
00
```

as expected.

(The 5-byte `click_report`s are fragmented into 4-byte and 1-byte messages, as there is a 4-byte maximum packet size for HID.)

I then changed `HID_EPIN_ADDR` in `usdb_hid.h` from `0x81` to `0x83`, to make the device use endpoint 3 for HID messages, instead of endpoint 1.

```
//#define HID_EPIN_ADDR                 0x81U
#define HID_EPIN_ADDR                 0x83U
```

With this change, everything continued to work, with the expected change that packets are being sent from x.x.3.  The packets still contain:

```
01 00 00 00
00
00 00 00 00
00
```

As far as I can see, this should *not* work, as I haven't yet allocated an address for endpoint 3 (`0x83`) in the PMA (packet memory area).

I do this, by editing usb_conf.c:

```
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EndPoint_Configuration */
  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x00 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x18);
  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x80 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x58);
  /* USER CODE END EndPoint_Configuration */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EndPoint_Configuration_HID */
  //HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x81 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x100);
  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x83 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x180);
  /* USER CODE END EndPoint_Configuration_HID */
  return USBD_OK;
}
```

Now, when I send the same `01 00 00 00 00` and `00 00 00 00 00` `click_reports` I see packet contents of:

```
58 00 2c 00
58
58 00 2c 00
58
```

I have traced the contents of the non-PMA buffer right down to `USB_WritePMA` in `stm32f3xx_ll_usb`.

The sending code (in `stm32f3xx_ll_usb`) is:

```
  /* IN endpoint */
  if (ep->is_in == 1U)
  {
    /*Multi packet transfer*/
    if (ep->xfer_len > ep->maxpacket)
    {
      len = ep->maxpacket;
      ep->xfer_len -= len;
    }
    else
    {
      len = ep->xfer_len;
      ep->xfer_len = 0U;
    }

    /* configure and validate Tx endpoint */
    if (ep->doublebuffer == 0U)
    {
      USB_WritePMA(USBx, ep->xfer_buff, ep->pmaadress, (uint16_t)len);
      PCD_SET_EP_TX_CNT(USBx, ep->num, len);
    }
    else
    {
```

Why is the data on the wire not the data that I give `USB_WritePMA`, once I've added `HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig(...` for endpoint address `0x83`?

---

Update:

If I change `usb_conf.c` to let endpoint address `0x83` use the PMA address that is normally used by `0x81`:

```
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EndPoint_Configuration */
  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x00 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x18);
  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x80 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x58);
  /* USER CODE END EndPoint_Configuration */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EndPoint_Configuration_HID */
  //HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x81 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x100);
  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x83 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x100);
  /* USER CODE END EndPoint_Configuration_HID */
```

the packets on the wire are still corrupted:

```
58 00 2c 00
58
58 00 2c 00
58
```

If I return `usb_conf.c` to its initial, generated, state (where `0x83` has no PMA address, and `0x81` uses `0x100`):

```
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EndPoint_Configuration */
  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x00 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x18);
  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x80 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x58);
  /* USER CODE END EndPoint_Configuration */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EndPoint_Configuration_HID */
  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x81 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x100);
  //HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x83 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x100);
  /* USER CODE END EndPoint_Configuration_HID */
```

the output works as expected:

```
01 00 00 00
00
00 00 00 00
00
```

---

Update 2:

I added a break-point in `USB_ActivateEndpoint()` in `stm32f3xx_ll_usb.c`.

Surprisingly this is only ever called for endpoint 0.

Therefore, the `ep->pmaadress` (sic) is never "written into hardware", and only used in higher-level code.

This must mean that the values of `pmaadress` for the endpoints are set to some default value, and I do not know the default value for endpoint `0x83` and so can't set it.

When I return to work on Friday, I will add debugging to read-out the default values.  If they do not exist, I will be very confused.

---

Update 3:

I added the following debugging:

```
uint16_t *tx_addr_ptr(USB_TypeDef *USBx, uint8_t ep_num) {
  register uint16_t *_wRegValPtr;
  register uint32_t _wRegBase = (uint32_t)USBx;
  _wRegBase += (uint32_t)(USBx)->BTABLE;
  _wRegValPtr = (uint16_t *)(_wRegBase + 0x400U + (((uint32_t)(ep_num) * 8U) * 2U));
  return _wRegValPtr;
}

uint16_t *rx_addr_ptr(USB_TypeDef *USBx, uint8_t ep_num) {
  register uint16_t *_wRegValPtr;
  register uint32_t _wRegBase = (uint32_t)USBx;
  _wRegBase += (uint32_t)(USBx)->BTABLE;
  _wRegValPtr = (uint16_t *)(_wRegBase + 0x400U + ((((uint32_t)(ep_num) * 8U) + 4U) * 2U));
  return _wRegValPtr;
}
...
HAL_StatusTypeDef USB_ActivateEndpoint(USB_TypeDef *USBx, USB_EPTypeDef *ep)
{
  ...
  int txaddrs[8] = {0};
  int rxaddrs[8] = {0};
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    txaddrs[i] = *tx_addr_ptr(USBx, i);
    rxaddrs[i] = *rx_addr_ptr(USBx, i);
  }
```

This showed me the following values (in the debugger):

```
txaddrs:
  0: 0x58
  1: 0xf5c4
  2: 0xc1c2
  3: 0x100

rxaddrs:
  0: 0x18
  1: 0xfa9b
  2: 0xcb56
  3: 0x0
```

These, unexpectedly, look correct.

`0x100` is the txaddr of endpoint 3, even though `USB_ActivateEndpoint()` has only just been called for the first time.

With a lot of grepping, I found that `PCD_SET_EP_TX_ADDRESS` (in `stm32f3xx_hal_pcd.h`) is not only used directly in `USB_ActivateEndpoint()`, but also in the `PCD_SET_EP_DBUF0_ADDR` macro from `stm32f3xx_hal_pcd.h.

`PCD_SET_EP_DBUF0_ADDR` does not appear to be used, so I do not know how the (changed) values from usbd_conf.c:

```
USBD_StatusTypeDef USBD_LL_Init(USBD_HandleTypeDef *pdev)
{
  ...
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EndPoint_Configuration */
  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x00 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x18);
  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x80 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x58);
  /* USER CODE END EndPoint_Configuration */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EndPoint_Configuration_HID */
  //HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x81 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x100);
  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x83 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x100);
  /* USER CODE END EndPoint_Configuration_HID */
```

get into the memory-mapped USB registers.

I can infer, from the presence of a `0x00` in `rxaddr[3]` (endpoint 3) that they happen in pairs (as there is no call to `HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x3 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x0);`).

---

Update 4:

After changing the device to use endpoint 1 again, the value of `0x100` in txaddrs[3] remained.  It was simply there from the last run, which removes a little confusion.

---

Update 5:

It's a BTABLE problem.  The BTABLE register has a value of 0x00, putting the btable at the start of the PMA.

The PMA looks like this:
[image: BTABLE]
and the start of the PMA is the btable.

I found:

```
PMAAddr + BASEADDR_BTABLE + 0x00000000 : EP0_TX_ADDR
PMAAddr + BASEADDR_BTABLE + 0x00000002 : EP0_TX_COUNT
PMAAddr + BASEADDR_BTABLE + 0x00000004 : EP0_RX_ADDR
PMAAddr + BASEADDR_BTABLE + 0x00000006 : EP0_RX_COUNT
PMAAddr + BASEADDR_BTABLE + 0x00000008 : EP1_TX_ADDR
PMAAddr + BASEADDR_BTABLE + 0x0000000A : EP1_TX_COUNT
PMAAddr + BASEADDR_BTABLE + 0x0000000C : EP1_RX_ADDR
PMAAddr + BASEADDR_BTABLE + 0x0000000E : EP1_RX_COUNT
PMAAddr + BASEADDR_BTABLE + 0x00000010 : EP2_TX_ADDR
PMAAddr + BASEADDR_BTABLE + 0x00000012 : EP2_TX_COUNT
PMAAddr + BASEADDR_BTABLE + 0x00000014 : EP2_RX_ADDR
PMAAddr + BASEADDR_BTABLE + 0x00000016 : EP2_RX_COUNT
```

on https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkaUASAZ/stm32-usb-endpoint-configuration-clarification-questions

This shows that endpoints `0x81` and `0x82` work because both `pma[4]` and `pma[8]` are set to `0x100`.

Endpoint `0x83` does not work because `pma[12]` is set to `0x0`.

This is consistent with the corrupted data having the value `58 00 2c 00` - the USB hardware was reading `pma[12]` and therefore sending the uint16_t's from `pma[0]`, which are `0x0058 0x002c`, sent reversed because of little-endianness.  (Note: the PMA is only 16-bits wide, so there are only two bytes at each address here.)

The call to `HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x82, PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x100);` does *not* set up the btable pointer at `pma[12]`, it just notes that PMA address to copy-to.

Now I just need to find where the content of the btable is being written...

Comment: This looks relevant: https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkdeRSAR/how-is-pmaadress-calculated-in-halpcdexpmaconfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TX address of EP3 is being overwritten by an incoming USB packet because it is located at the same offset in PMA as the RX buffer for the control EP0. The original code works okay because it only uses EP1.

How exactly these offsets are set depends on what's in the layers of STMCube, and my copy seems to be different, but this appears where the offsets of RX and TX buffers in EP0 are set in the OP's code:

```
HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x00 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x18);
HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x80 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x58);
```

These constants need to be changed to 0x40 and 0x80 (for example).

In my version, these offsets are defined in a header file and there is also EP_NUM constant, but how it's used is unclear.

Everything else seems to be just distractions.

Comment: I think you may be on the right track, as I haven't encountered EP_NUM yet.  I can't find it with `grep -R "EP_NUM" *` in the project directory.  (I have seen that various loops over endpoints use `for (i = 0U; i < hpcd->Init.dev_endpoints; i++)`, but `dev_endpoints` is initialised to `8` in `usbd_conf.c`.)

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  This was exactly correct.  (I also pushed EP3's buffer up from `0x100` to `0x128`, to be consistent.)

Answer (score 0):

A work-around is to add the two lines following `// correct PMA BTABLE` to `HAL_PCD_EP_Transmit()` in `stm32f3xx_hal_pcd.c`:

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_PCD_EP_Transmit(PCD_HandleTypeDef *hpcd, uint8_t ep_addr, uint8_t *pBuf, uint32_t len)
{
  PCD_EPTypeDef *ep;

  ep = &hpcd->IN_ep[ep_addr & EP_ADDR_MSK];

  /*setup and start the Xfer */
  ep->xfer_buff = pBuf;
  ep->xfer_len = len;
  ep->xfer_count = 0U;
  ep->is_in = 1U;
  ep->num = ep_addr & EP_ADDR_MSK;

  // correct PMA BTABLE
  uint32_t *btable = (uint32_t *) USB_PMAADDR;
  btable[ep->num * 4] = ep->pmaadress;
  ...
```

This causes a correction to the location of endpoint 3's TX buffer before *every* write.  This is wasteful, but it was not sufficient to set it once, as the value in `pma[12]` was being overwritten.

I have used this workaround in successfully creating a composite CDC (serial) and HID device.

To solve this properly, I need an answer to: [What initialises the contents of the STM32's USB BTABLE when the __HAL_RCC_USB_CLK_ENABLE() macro is executed in HAL_PCD_MspInit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59948198/what-initialises-the-contents-of-the-stm32s-usb-btable-when-the-hal-rcc-usb-c)

Comment: I've just found: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf which seems to contain all the information that was missing from the individual chip datasheets.

Comment: Why is rxaddrs[0]  0x18? This seems wrong. Assuming BTABLE is at the beginning of the PMA, then there is EP0 RX buffer, then EP0 TX buffer (at 0x58 = 0x18 + 64 - ok), this means Cube only allocates buffers space for *3* endpoints. The value 0 may be written as a part of USB reception because it is the same area as RX buffer for EP 0.

Comment: What is the value of EP_NUM? It should be at least 4 if you use EP 3.

Comment: I can't find it with grep -R "EP_NUM" * in the project directory.

Comment: Re: rxaddrs[0] - Is `0x18` 24 addresses into the 16-bit PMA or `0x18` bytes / 12 addresses into the PMA?  If it's bytes, then received packets on EP0 would be written into `pma[12]` overwriting the TX buffer address for EP3.

Comment: Your pma[2] is 0x18. This is byte offset into the PMA, as the hardware sees it, specifying the RX buffer location for EP0. Yes, this is what likely happens.

Comment: I'm not sure where it is set in the generated code, but in my ST USB examples, EP_NUM is defined in usb_conf.h, along with the BTABLE value and endpoint numbers, etc.

Comment: Actually, I see now that EP0 offsets in the buffers are hardcoded there too. I thought the code does it dynamically. I will add my settings to the answer as an example.

Comment: Re: "Your pma[2] is 0x18."  Yes, I think we now know why the EP3 TX buffer address is being overwritten.

Comment: Are you using CubeMX/CubeIDE?  The string `EP_NUM` does not appear in the project.  The contents of the BTABLE "miraculously" appears when the USB clock is started.  I cannot find what code writes it, nor where the values come from.

Comment: I am spared from CubeMX. I have various pieces of it though. The content of BTABLE miraculously appears because it is stored in RAM that preserves its content over resets.

Comment: Isn't this from the code you posted:  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x00 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x18);
  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x80 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x58);

Comment: No, `HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig()` initialises values in `hcpd`, `hcpd->IN_ep[]` and `hcpd->OUT_ep[]`.  It doesn't (directly) write to the BTABLE, or call any other function.  Those `hcpd` values are used when data is written into TX buffers in the PMA, or read from RX buffers, but not written into the BTABLE directly.

Comment: Re: "RAM that preserves its content over resets" - I zero the PMA at the start of `main()`.  It must come from somewhere else.

Comment: Do you zero it before clock is enabled?

Comment: In my copy of F3 Cube, BTABLE address is set in HAL_PCD_EP_Open() using the PCD_SET_EP_TX_ADDRESS() macro.

Comment: It's in stm32f3xx_hal_pcd.c

Comment: Yes, I zero it before the USB clock enable macro.  It is at that point that the content of the BTABLE in PMA becomes non-zero.

Comment: `HAL_PCD_EP_Open()` calls `USB_ActivateEndpoint()` which uses the `PCD_SET_EP_TX_ADDRESS()` macro, but I only saw this called for EP0 (when I added a breakpoint).  I will check this again tomorrow.

Comment: Writing to USB RAM while it has no running clock does nothing.

Comment: In essence :-) you need to change 0x18 to 0x40 and 0x58 to 0x80, and make sure other buffers do not overlap too. Eventually these values propagate to BTABLE in some way or another.

Comment: Thanks, I will change the buffers tomorrow.  I did not expect "Writing to USB RAM while it has no running clock does nothing.".